# how to count operators and operand from equation?

Tags: math, operators

**6 * 35 + 8 – (25 / 5)**

1)How many operators and operands are in equation?

2)Is parenthesis considered as operator?

3)Inside the parenthesis operator and operand is considered?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Question asked in theory exam.

Comment: OK, so this is for a course you are studying. What do your course materials say about operators and operands?